# Tipo decimal Phinx Slim Framework

Tags: slim

Como posso criar um tipo decimal na Migration do Phinx, veja como está atualmente:

```
$oss->addColumn('valor','decimal', ['limit' => 10.2]);
```

Já tentei de várias maneiras e não consigo, ele sempre gera somente 10,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona assim:

```
$oss->addColumn('valor','decimal', ['precision' => 10, 'scale' => 8]);
```